# why doesn't the $(this).attr's work? They bring back 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I have a few buttons and because I don't want to code the same thing for each button I was trying to make a dynamic event handler that could manage all the buttons based on the .selected-pack class but all the $(this) attributes are coming back undefined although there is a value.

This is the js:

```
//Function In Test! 
$('.selected-pack').click(function(event) {

    if($("#mainconsole").val() == "") {
        alert("Select Your Console!")
        return;
    }


    if($("#paymentmethod").val() == "") {
        alert("Select Your Preferred Payment Method!")
        return;
    }

     $("#selectConsolediv").fadeOut("medium", function() {
                    $("#choosePlatformLI").removeClass("active");



        var packipn = $(this).attr('data-ipn');
        var packipnpp = $(this).attr('data-ipnpp');
        var packname = $(this).attr('data-name');
        var packprice = "";

                    console.log(packname);
        if ($("#mainconsole").val() == "PS"){
           packprice = $(this).attr('data-psprice');
        }

        if ($("#mainconsole").val() == "XBOX") {
           packprice = $(this).attr('data-xbprice');
        }


        // Skrill
        $("#mainamount").val(packprice);
        $("#mainipn").val(packipn);
        $("#maindesc").val(packname);
        $("#maindiscount").val($("#discount1").val());

         // PayPal
        $("#mainamountpp").val(packprice);
        $("#mainipnpp").val(packipnpp);
        $("#ppitemname").val(packname);
        $("#maindiscountpp").val($("#discount1").val());


        $("#checkoutPackName").text(packname);
        $("#checkoutCode").text($("#discount1").val());
        $("#checkoutPrice").text("£" + packprice);

                    $("#checkoutdiv").fadeIn("medium", function() {
                        $("#checkoutLI").addClass("active");
                    });
     });

});
```

Do any of you spot an error? Please give me a comment as soon as possible, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you expect `this` to refer to the clicked `.selected-pack` element or to the `#selectConsolediv` element? Based on what you're written here, I would expect it to the `#selectConsolediv` element.

Comment: .selected-pack element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the scope of `$(this)` changes inside the `fadeOut()` callback.  Try adding:

```
var self = $(this);
```

at the top immediately after `$('.selected-pack').click(function(event) {` and use `self` instead throughout.